# get JSON object using jquery with ajax call from controller to view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying for few hours now to find out the solution of how to get a JSON object back:

This is my function in view together with everything I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-link").click(function () {
        var chairChosen = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var perfDateId = $("#perfDate").attr("id");
        var totalCost = $("#totalMoney").html();
        window.alert(perfDateId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Booking/ReserveSeat1/?id=' + chairChosen + '&perfDateId=' + perfDateId,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data1) {

                $("#test").append(typeof data1);
                $("#test").append(" notConverted" + data1.Number);
                $("#test").append(" notConverted" + data1["Number"]);
                var result1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data1);
                $("#test").append("Converted jquery" + result1.Number);
                $("#test").append("Converted jquery" + result1["Number"]);
                var result2 = JSON.stringify(data1);
                var object1 = data1;
                $("#test").append("get object " + object1.Number)
                $("#test").append("Converted parse" + result2.Number);
                $("#test").append("Converted parse" + result2["Number"]);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $(that).remove();
                DisplayError(error.statusText);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I want to mention data I don't want to send JSON data, I only expect to receive it.

The following code is in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReserveSeat1(int id, int perfDateId)
    {

        BookSeatResult bookSeat = new BookSeatResult()
        {
            Number = 10,
            Result = "a string"
        };

        return Json(bookSeat);
    }
```

also tried returning a JSON response from controller.

it's an mvc web app in asp.net core.

Not to forget to mention that when i do the call the controller responds, and it does return an object type

Comment: as i mentioned I am using asp.net core (version 2.2, I should have said), and JsonRequestBehavior has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core 1.0, if i try using it it says it does not exist in the current context

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: @mdln97 You should be able to retrieve the JSON data with `POST` method.

Comment: JsonRequestBehavior does not exist in the current context, that is the error;  and there is no method for Json taking two objects

Comment: could you try  JsonResult instead of ActionResult

Comment: @jom there is no difference, still does not work

Comment: there should not make any difference with JsonResult, however I tried, still no succes

Comment: 1.During Debugging  does your method  "ReserveSeat1" gets Hit... secondly are you able to see it in network tab .AS it might be url and  route issue

Comment: yes it gets hit and yes it appears in the network tab

Comment: Try returning it as OkObjectResult  ----> return Ok(Json(Enumerable.Range(0, t + id).ToArray()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for getting involved, after spending some time with your suggestions I managed to find a way to work around:

```
newObj.Add(bookSeat.Number.ToString());
        newObj.Add(bookSeat.Result);

        return Json(newObj.ToArray());
```

I am returning an array now and I access it in view as follows:

```
  $("#test").append(data1[1]);
```

Also, I analysed the data that is being received back, so I did the following:

```
$("#test").append(data1["result"]);
```

and now i get the expected string

Answer (score 3):

For Json object, it is case-sensitive which means `data1.Number` and `data1.number` are different.

For Asp.Net Core serialize, its default serializer is `camelCase` which means, the `return Json(bookSeat);` will return a json string like below:

`{"number":10,"result":"a string"}`

For this string, if you need to access `number` and `result`, you need to use `number` instead of `Number`.

Try

```
$("#test").append(data1.number);
$("#test").append(data1.result);
```

If you want to use `data1.Number`, you need to change the asp.net core to return `PascalCase` with configuration below in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - who would know this? I spent an hour trying to debug this and went through two different methods of returning JSON to the browser, including using JsonResult and JObject serialize. What a pain!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".nav-link").click(function () {
    var chairChosen = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var perfDateId = $("#perfDate").attr("id");
    var totalCost = $("#totalMoney").html();
    window.alert(perfDateId);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Booking/ReserveSeat1/?id=' + 
   chairChosen + '&perfDateId=' + perfDateId,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data1) {

            $("#test").append(typeof data1);
            $("#test").append(" notConverted" + 
   data1[0]["Number"]);
            $("#test").append(" notConverted" + 
  data1[0]["Number"]);
            var result1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data1);
            $("#test").append("Converted jquery" + 
 result1[0]["Number"];
            $("#test").append("Converted jquery" + 
result1[0]["Number"]);
            var result2 = JSON.stringify(data1);
            var object1 = data1;
            $("#test").append("get object " + 
object1[0]["Number"])
            $("#test").append("Converted parse" + 
 result2[0].["Number"]);
            $("#test").append("Converted parse" + 
 result2[0]["Number"]);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $(that).remove();
            DisplayError(error.statusText);
        }
    });

});
```

The 0 in the data1[0]["Number"],result1[0]["Number"] is the Key.
Indicating the row index in the array.
I also added booSeat and returned as JSON Serialized array as shown below.

```
[HttpGet]
   public ActionResult ReserveSeat1(int id, int 
 perfDateId)
{

    BookSeatResult bookSeat = new BookSeatResult()
    {
        Number = 10,
        Result = "a string"
    };
 List<BookSeatResult> bookSeatList = new 
 List<BookSeatResult>();
    bookSeatList.Add(bookSeat);
    return 
    Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bookSeatList
    .ToArray()));
}
```

The Pattern to retrieve Items in the json data within an ajax function is :

```
  $.ajax({
       ....
    success: function (data1) {
     var item1 = data1[0]["Attribute1"];
    }
```

Comment: For ASP.NET Core Application

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the `HttpGet` attribute from the method or change it to `HttpPost`, and then do AJAX `POST`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Booking/ReserveSeat1/?id=' + chairChosen + '&perfDateId=' + perfDateId,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data1) {

  }

//...
```

Comment: Try returning it as OkObjectResult ----> return Ok(Json(Enumerable.Range(0, t + id).ToArray()));